# *ngIf only works sometimes with async pipe

Tags: angular, observable

I have a situation where this ngIf is not working some of the time even though I can see the value is correct:

```
<div id="overlay" *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></div>
<div class="page-content" [class.inactive]="isLoading$ | async">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have the observable twice, and for the **[class.inactive]** if **isLoading** is updated I can see the result, but for the **ngIf** right above it, it only works half the time.

I do have onpush change detection turned on, however that shouldn't matter, also this is a select from NGRX store.  I doubt either of these two mentions have are the cause, but just giving the facts.

Update- If I do this it works:

```
    <div id="overlay" [class.loading]="isLoading$ | async"></div>
    <div class="page-content" [class.inactive]="isLoading$ | async">

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

I would really like to know why this doesn't work with the *ngIf consistently, if anyone has ran into this before please share :)

Comment: You can use it as many times as you want. Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console.  one of them works consistently (the class.inactive) and the other (the ngIf) works inconsistently however its easy to see the state of isLoading$ is proper, cause I can print it to the screen and of course the class.inactive is good

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: I just tried re-creating this exactly, but the *ngIf strategy works every time. I think our only hope is a stackblitz repro... I'm really curious about this!

Comment: @Jesse - share your working version of this as an answer, if its working with the above scenerio (NGRX select, and the html) you get the points.  Just means its something on my side (deeper) not a surface level issue like I assumed it was.  I am using, angular 8, ngrx 8.6.0

Comment: @Harleyz Hopefully this helps you. I had to put it in a github repo since stackblitz wasn't letting me set the Angular version to 8. https://github.com/jessejohnsohn/ngif-tester-harleyz

Comment: I've tested your repo and it works. Here is stackblitz form your repo https://stackblitz.com/github/jessejohnsohn/ngif-tester-harleyz. Can you share more code from your initial project: template, component's code, etc. Everything you think can be related with an issue.

Comment: Hey it might help to see what your isLoading$ is producing, by adding this.isLoading$.subscribbe(console.log) in your component

Comment: @gabriel, if I print the value for isloading to the screen, it is always the expected value.

Comment: @Dmitrii - i will take a look to see if I can spot an issue by adding the route.  Thank you for the assist.

Comment: Hey @Harleyz is just an idea, as you know isLoading$ is a stream, in the HTML you see the final value, in angular | async first returns null, and then subscribes I will imagine it goes from true to false, you might be getting something weird that makes the ngIf  different to that [class.x] expression work differently, once you get the values you could hard code them directly in each case and see which one is the one that makes it weird, might work

Comment: DmitriiMakarov or Jesse - if you add this to an answer I can mark it as the good answer.  I tried to extend the stackblitz to follow more my approach.  funny thing is I messed up on the routing for a second which was causing an error in the console and the class worked still but the ngif didn't.  Fixed it and they both work now, I am sure something down stream is causing the issue but without an error anywhere in my app will be hard to find.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dmn1bu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was offered in comments but not as an answer.  The issue is in no form related to angular, it’s something deeper in my code.  Marking complete so no one else tries to follow up on this as the answer is nothing is wrong with the code, it’s something else, somewhere else.   The work around with the class offered in the question also is a good work around if someone else happens to experience something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put  `*ngIf=` on `router-outlet`. Because your angular app will load the routes on the call of router-outlet. So you should put ngIf on the nested components.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid double subscription you can do as follow

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{isLoading: isLoading$ | async} as source">
  <div id="overlay" *ngIf="sourcec.isLoading"></div>
  <div class="page-content" [class.inactive]="sourcec.isLoading">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I tested this, and get the same result.  The ngIf works inconsistently and the class.inactive works always.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading$ | async as loaded; else loading" >

<div class="page-content" [class.inactive]="loaded">
  Is Loading but with red
</div>

</ng-container>


<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff...
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="overlay" ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></div>
```

or this:

```
<ng-container id="overlay" *ngIf="isLoading$ | async">

</ng-container>
```

or use span or div or regular html tag:

```
<span id="overlay" *ngIf="isLoading$ | async">
```